# Split column data after last delimiter into new column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following data example in a google sheet:

| url |
| --- |
| https://www.testwebsite.com/compute/v1/test/images-prd-5d4d/glob/images/testimage-vsfd |
| [https://www.testwebsite.com/compute/v1/test/images-prd-5d4d/glob/images/testimage-sdawr|](https://www.testwebsite.com/compute/v1/test/images-prd-5d4d/glob/images/testimage-sdawr%7C) |

What I need is to extract the data after the substring "images/" and have something like this:

| url | extract |
| --- | --- |
| https://www.testwebsite.com/compute/v1/test/images-prd-5d4d/glob/images/testimage-vsfd | testimage-vsfd |
| [https://www.testwebsite.com/compute/v1/test/images-prd-5d4d/glob/images/testimage-sdawr|testimage-sdawr](https://www.testwebsite.com/compute/v1/test/images-prd-5d4d/glob/images/testimage-sdawr%7Ctestimage-sdawr) |  |

I have created the following function to get this but is only extracting everything after the last "-":

```
function strip() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet6");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1).getDisplayValues().flat();
  let vo = vs.map(s => [s.match(/\b[0-9A-Zaz/]+$/gi)[0]]);
  sh.getRange(2,2,vo.length,1).setValues(vo);
}
```

What is the proper way to extract the data it's mentioned above?

Comment: Do they always have /images/ before the image name?

Comment: @TheWizEd Yes they always have that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this on Apps Script:

```
function strip() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet6");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1).getDisplayValues().flat();
  const string= "/images/";

  for (i = 0; i < vs.length; i++){

  //Using substrings:
  const extract = vs[i].substring(vs[i].indexOf(string) + string.length);
  sh.getRange(i+2,2).setValue(extract);

  //Using .split():
  // const extract = vs[i].split(string); //This splits the string in 2.
  // sh.getRange(i+2,2).setValue(extract[1]); //Adding the second part of the array;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it like a custom function you can try the following code:

```
function strip(url) {
  var text = url;
  var splittedValue = text.split("/images/");
  return splittedValue[1];
  
}
```

It would work something like this:

#### Input:

[image]

#### Result:

[image]

The script can also be changed to get a specific range of data automatically so that every time you add a new URL you get the result in the next column automatically, but this is just for you to get the idea.

#### References:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

Answer (score 0):

Say your URLs are in `A2:A`. You can use

```
=arrayformula(if(isblank(A2:A),,substitute(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"/images/[A-Za-z0-9-_|/\.]+"),"/images/","")))
```

Use native formulas where possible. That is more efficient.

If you already dealt with the issue with run time delay, and have a need to use custom function for other reasons, you can match with the `"/image/"` part and then remove it, or, alternatively, specifying a capturing group. Also don't forget other value characters such as `_`, `|`.